# equivalent of ( "A1:C5") in 1,1 Notation

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

I am working with google's spreadsheet application.

There, the programming language is called scripts.

To address a cell or several cells (here called Range) you may use one of three different addressing methods:

1. "A1"-method
2. "R1C1"-method
3. the method using just integers to assign a cell "1,1".

All three examples point to the very first cell in a spreadsheet. In order to point to several cells you have to use arrays. An example in the "A1" method would be: "B3:C5".

I did not find the array-notation for the "1,1" notation, which is prescribed for using the element "LastRow", to find the last row in an existing data-list.

My question is therefore:

What is the notation for the "1,1"-notation for arrays?

Thanks
Fred Casadei

Comment: What is 1,1 form? What is the expected output for the example given?

Comment: I'm guessing from the "A1:C5" that you're using some sort of spreadsheet application?  Can you clarify what application you are using and maybe add a tag for it to your question?

Comment: Can you add a small working snippet of your script related to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the `range` from a Sheet, you can use one of these methods.

#### Methods

**1. `getRange(row, column)`**

This method is used to retrieve the `range` of a cell given the `row` and the `column` at which this one is found.

**2. `getRange(row, column, numRows)`**

This method is used to retrieve the `range` of a cell given the `row`, the `column` and the `number of rows` at which this one is found.

**3. `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`**

This method is used to retrieve the `range` of a cell given the `row`, the `column`, the `number of rows` and the `number of columns` at which this one is found.

**4. `getRange(a1Notation)`**

This method is used to retrieve the `range` of a cell given the `A1` notation corresponding to it.

Therefore, if the range you are trying to retrieve is `A1:C5`, the best methods would be the `3`rd and the `4`th one and you can use them like this.

#### Snippet

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range3 = ss.getRange(1,1,5,3).getValues();
Logger.log(range3);
var range4 = ss.getRange("A1:C5").getValues();
Logger.log(range4);
```

#### Explanation

You **cannot** use the `1`st method as this one gets the range only based on the `row` and `column` and since you have a range with multiple rows and columns this is not the appropriate method for it. Same goes for the `2`nd method as this will still not return the whole data present in the range.

#### Reference

- [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column)
- [getRange(row, column, numRows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows)
- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)
- [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation);
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues).

Comment: I will try your recommendations.